# How to redirect a user with a timer

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, timer

Doing a kind of quizz, I would like to set a limited time to answer questions.

So the user just need to put his answer in the form, and validate. Validate will redirect to the page process.php, which will check everything.

If the user doesn't answer in time, it will sumbit the empty form. (because false answer and empty answer got same repercussions)

I know there are some way, with meta tag (html), or header (php), but this isn't really what I'm looking for, cause of code customisation, or security reasons.

Actually, I got this code.

```
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">10</span> second(s).</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'process.php';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
```

But this isn't what I'm looking for, cause the user can easily change the timer, to set a bigger value.

I have also looked at [PHP function microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), to put it in session, and check in my process.php if the timer isn't changed. But I failed.

- Is there an easy way to solve this problem ?
- How to really secure answer time, and prevent timer change ?

Comment: You can not prevent it on the client. You would need to keep track of times on the server and you need to remember that it takes time for requests to move over the wire and for the page to load so it is NOT 10 seconds in PHP.

Comment: You want to do it through javascript only??....Also possible using HTML also like this.. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://www.google.com/" />` , so to redirect after 10 seconds..

Comment: you can also store a date on the server, and if the user modified the timer, and answers the question later the server would reject the request.

Comment: so basically the client-side would be purely aestetic

Comment: Your server should make a comparaison of time when the form is submitted with the original sent. If the user cheated, you can send an error message.

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco, or ban them for cheating :)

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar : Meta isn't really what i'm looking for, cause it need to sumbit the form at the end.
@ epoch : Yes, this would be only visual.
@ GuillaumeCisco : Yup, but in this way, UTC or loading delay won't affect the problem ?

Comment: @Jerem.Bartman. Yes it will. But this is the only clean way to do it. If your servers are good enough, you won't have problems. Think to video games servers with pings less to 10ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The only way to bypass the user from "cheating" his way out of the timer is to make the timer dependent on the server time. This means that you have to have some data passed by the server. eg Every time a user starts answering a question, set a session object (or something equivalent) and then clear it when a user finishes answering it. So when user starts answering a question, check if the data exists, and calculate the remaining time.
2. If you dont want the timer to be dependent on the server, you can make the function anonymous. When the function is anonymous, you can get some level of secrecy.

.

```
function(){
    var a = setInterval(function(){ 
        i = document.getElementById('counter');
        if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
            clearInterval(a);
            document.getElementById('formName').submit();
        }
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML, 10) - 1;
     },1000);
}();
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is what I was thinking for, except about anonymous fucntion.

But about server time, UTC or loading time won't be a problem ?

Comment: Loading time will have an effect. There is almost no way you can avoid this. You have to handle for an error time of upto 1-2 secs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery to simply submit the form when countdown is over like this :

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
$(function() {
    var countDown = 5000;

    // Will occur after "countDown" / 1000 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
            $("#theQuizzForm").submit();
        },
        countDown
    );
});
```

Assuming your `form` is shaped like this :

```
<form method = "whatever" action="process.php">
    <!-- html elements -->
</form>
```

Using `setTimeout` will submit the form **after** countDown / 1000 seconds, which here is 5 secs.